# Python/Django Test Framework: Response code was 200 (expected 200)

Tags: python, django, testing

So I am using Django's test framework, and in this case im testing update_password_view that I ve created on top of the built-in PasswordChangeForm.

Could someone please help me with the error from below?

After I run tests I get the following error:

> AssertionError: [] is not true : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200(expected 200)

Here is the code:

```
#views.py
class UpdatePassword(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:home')
    template_name = 'accounts/password.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        # get the number of unseen messages
        context['inbox_count'] = Message.objects.filter(
        ~Q(sender=self.request.user), Q(seen=False), 
        (Q(chat__user1=self.request.user) |\
        Q(chat__user2=self.request.user))).count()
        return context

#tests.py
def test_update_password_view(self):
        credentials = {
            'old_password': '123secret', 
            'password1': '321secret', 
            'password2': '321secret',
        }
        response = self.client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/change-password/', 
                    credentials, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/posts/', status_code=200, 
        target_status_code=200)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `status_code=302` if it's a redirect?  The `target_status_code=200` is what the final point is after the redirect.

Comment: hey, thanks for helping. please check my reply below. sorry forgot to mention that i ve tried what u ve suggested.

Comment: So the error is not in the code you show, but elsewhere.  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/change-password/` is NOT redirecting to `/posts/`, and the assertion error is telling you so.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a user and log them in before running the password change redirect test?  I explain in my answer below.

Comment: thanks so much for helping Raphael. I ve logged in user in setUp method of my class, and the proove that is is working is the two other tests passing assertion successfully (sign up and another profile update). This one should pass aswell but the error 200 status code != 200 status code is really odd to me!? It seems like a bug or smth.

Answer (score 0):

`status_code` inside `assertRedirects` has to be redirect status code, which should be 3XX. In your occasion it has to be `302`. See more at [docs](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.test.TestCase.assertRedirects).

For the proper behaviour you should replace this:

```py
self.assertRedirects(response, '/posts/', status_code=200,  target_status_code=200)
```

With this:

```py
self.assertRedirects(response, '/posts/', status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

By the way, it's similar to this:

```py
self.assertRedirects(response, '/posts/')
```

Comment: Hey guys,

Thanks for helping and sorry for the late reply. I am also sorry since I ve forgot to say that I ve tried using 302 in status_code=302 paramether, but I am than getting almost the same error:
AssertionError: [] is not true : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)

Also, I ve tested this manually and I got 302 followed by 200 status code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but perhaps the issue is that it is not redirecting because the user is not created, or logged in with the old password.  Try creating a user, logging them in, then running the test.

```py
#tests.py

def test_update_password_view(self):

        credentials = {
            'old_password': '123secret', 
            'password1': '321secret', 
            'password2': '321secret',
        }

        # Create and login the user
        self.client.user = User.objects.create(username="testuser", password="123secret")
        c = Client()
        logged_in = c.login(username='testuser', password='123secret')

        response = self.client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/change-password/', 
                    credentials, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/posts/', status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```